# TCPSocket.send() doesn't send immediately?

Tags: firefox-os

I used TCPSocket.send() when I developed app on firefox os. But it doesn't work well. Server can't receive the data immediately, only when I shut simulator down, server can receive the data. It a problem of buffer?

Comment: You could show the code you're actually trying with `TCPSocket.send`.